# How to display GUI message indicating which checkbutton(s) and radiobutton have been selected in tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter, radio-button, message

I am super new to Python and programming in general. I'm messing around in `tkinter` trying to make a silly and simple program so I can get more comfortable with it.

What I am doing with my program is asking for the user's name, age, if they remember certain events, and if they feel old or not. Like I said, it is supposed to be a light hearted program just to put my skills to the test.

Now I wonder, how to display GUI message indicating which checkbutton(s) and radiobutton have been selected in tkinter in Python?

Here is the code and a screenshot. I'll include a screenshot of my results but I can get the name and age to work like it should but can't get the message to appear correctly in the GUI with the checkboxes or radio button.

```
from tkinter import *

class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.geometry("600x400")
        self.master.title("How to tell if you're old")
        self.event = NONE
        self.old = NONE
        self.grid()

    #user name and age
        self.prompt = Label(self, text="What's your name?")
        self.prompt.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)

        self.input_name = Entry(self)
        self.input_name.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5)

        self.prompt = Label(self, text="How old are you?")
        self.prompt.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)

        self.input_age = Entry(self)
        self.input_age.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10)

    #user asks user if they remember certain events
        self.prompt = Label(self, text="Which of these events do"
                                   "you remember (may select more than one)?")
        self.prompt.grid(row=3, columnspan=5, pady=5)

        self.wheel_event = IntVar()
        self.check_wheel_event = Checkbutton(self, text="Invention of the wheel",
                                         variable=self.wheel_event, command=self.set_response_event)
        self.check_wheel_event.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5)

        self.firstFlight_event = IntVar()
        self.check_firstFlight_event = Checkbutton(self, text="First flight",
                                               variable=self.firstFlight_event, command=self.set_response_event)
        self.check_firstFlight_event.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5)

        self.Berlin_Wall_event = IntVar()
        self.check_Berlin_Wall_event = Checkbutton(self, text="Berlin Wall",
                                               variable=self.Berlin_Wall_event, command=self.set_response_event)
        self.check_Berlin_Wall_event.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=5)

        self.millennium_event = IntVar()
        self.check_millennium_event = Checkbutton(self, text="Millennium",
                                              variable=self.millennium_event, command=self.set_response_event)
        self.check_millennium_event.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=5)

    #user answers if they think they're old and if they want to know how
        # old they'll be in 10, 15, or 20 years
        self.prompt = Label(self, text="Do you consider yourself old?")
        self.prompt.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=5)

        self.feel_old = IntVar()
        self.feel_old.set(4)

        self.not_sure_old = Radiobutton(self, text="Not sure",
                                    variable=self.feel_old, value="0")
        self.not_sure_old.grid(row=6, column=0)

        self.no_old = Radiobutton(self, text="No",
                              variable=self.feel_old, value="1")
        self.no_old.grid(row=6, column=1)

        self.yes_old = Radiobutton(self, text="Yes",
                               variable=self.feel_old, value="2")
        self.yes_old.grid(row=6, column=2)

    #submit button
        self.button_submit = Button(self, text='Submit',
                                command=self.submit_click)
        self.button_submit.grid
        self.button_submit.grid(row=9, column=3, padx=10)

        self.my_name = StringVar()
        self.message = Label(self, textvariable=self.my_name)
        self.message.grid(columnspan=2, pady=10)

        self.my_age = StringVar()
        self.message = Label(self, textvariable=self.my_age)
        self.message.grid(columnspan=2, pady=10)

    #response
    def set_response_event(self):
        #remembering events
        if self.wheel_event.get() == 1:
            self.event = "wheel"
        elif self.firstFlight_event.get() == 1:
            self.event = "firstFlight"
        elif self.Berlin_Wall_event.get() == 1:
            self.event = "Berlin_Wall"
        elif self.millennium_event.get() == 1:
            self.event = "millennium"

    def set_response_old(self):
        #feeling old
        if self.not_sure_old.get() == "0":
            self.old = "not_sure_old"
        elif self.no_old.get() == "1":
            self.old = "no_old"
        elif self.yes_old.get() == "2":
            self.old = "yes_old"

    def submit_click(self):
        output_message = 'Well ' + self.input_name.get() + ', to begin with you are ' + self.input_age.get() + '.\n'
        output_message += 'You remember the ' + self.event +'.\n'
        output_message += 'This means you are ' + self.old + '.'

        self.my_name.set(output_message)

frame05 = MyFrame()
frame05.mainloop()
```

Here is what I get:
[image]

I realize I'm probably doing this the hard way but I feel like I'm really close. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you are never calling `set_response_old(self)` that I can tell. Secondly you are trying to compare strings to integers, which doesn't get caught in your `if` statements. Try rewriting the last two functions like this:

```
    def set_response_old(self):
        #feeling old
        if self.feel_old.get() == 0:
            self.old = "not sure old"
        elif self.feel_old.get() == 1:
            self.old = "no old"
        elif self.feel_old.get() == 2:
            self.old = "yes old"

    def submit_click(self):
        self.set_response_old()
        output_message = 'Well ' + self.input_name.get() + ', to begin with you are ' + self.input_age.get() + '.\n'
        output_message += 'You remember the ' + self.event + '.\n'
        output_message += 'This means you are ' + self.old + '.'
        self.my_name.set(output_message)
```

When I run this it outputs

> This means you are yes old.

Which I *think* is what you were going for.

**@EDIT**

As for getting the list of remembered events to show...You can add `self.events_remembered = []` to your `__init__` section to create a place to store the data (it's not required to be in the init section as the code below would make it anyways, but it's good practice!) and then change your `set_response` function as such:

```
    def set_response_event(self):
    #remembering events
    self.events_remembered = [] # reset each time we are determining pressed events (so we don't just keep adding duplicates, and also remove any unchecked boxes)
    if self.wheel_event.get() == 1:
        self.events_remembered.append("wheel")
    if self.firstFlight_event.get() == 1:
        self.events_remembered.append("firstFlight")
    if self.Berlin_Wall_event.get() == 1:
        self.events_remembered.append("Berlin Wall")
    if self.millennium_event.get() == 1:
        self.events_remembered.append("millennium")
```

You are correct in thinking that the `if` will only catch the first one, but there is no rule against having a series of `if` statements like shown!

Finally you can update your `submit_click` function to search for this information and display the formatted list

```
def submit_click(self):
    self.set_response_old()
    self.set_response_event() # use the function we just updated
    print(self.events_remembered)
    output_message = 'Well ' + self.input_name.get() + ', to begin with you are ' + self.input_age.get() + '.\n'
    output_message += 'You remember the ' + ", ".join(self.events_remembered) + '.\n'
    output_message += 'This means you are ' + self.old + '.'
    self.my_name.set(output_message)
```

Here we use `", ".join(iterable_list)` to convert our python list to a nice comma separated list instead!

If this solved your question I would appreciate if you could accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the post! If you really just like me you can click to upvote me too XD

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: The other trouble I have is making the check boxes work correctly. If I select two or more check boxes it'll hit the first one and just return that. I know it has to do with my if statements but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am leaning towards it needing to be a loop.

Comment: @BryanH I've updated my post to show how you can fix the formatting of check box information displays!

Comment: That did the trick, thank you so much! I marked that answer as correct. I knew I was somewhat close but just couldn't see it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

To get all the checkbox values to the output, make self.event attribute a list

```
def __init__self():
    ...
    ...
    self.event=[]
```

and when you call the set_response_event function, append those string values to that list.

```
def set_response_event(self):
    #remembering events
    if self.wheel_event.get() == 1:
        self.event.append("wheel")
    elif self.firstFlight_event.get() == 1:
        self.event.append("firstFlight")
    elif self.Berlin_Wall_event.get() == 1:
        self.event.append("Berlin_Wall")
    elif self.millennium_event.get() == 1:
        self.event.append("millennium")
```

Finally print the list using .join function

```
'You remember the ' + ', '.join(self.event) + '\n'
```